# error in unreachable if block

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am trying to do the following:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T * ptr){
    ...a lot of code ...
    if(std::is_base_of<Bar<T>,T>::value){
        Bar<T> & bar = *ptr;
        ...a lot of code ...
    }
    ...a lot of code    
}
```

if I am compiling this function with a  which is a subclass of Bar, everything works fine, but if I try to compile with a  which isnt, I am getting an error at the

```
Bar<T> & bar = *ptr;
```

line.
How an this be, since this line shoundnt be executed when `T` isnt a subclass of `Bar<T>` ?
And if this is not the common way to do this, how can I achieve this in a correct way?

Comment: "Not executed" isn't the same as "not compiled".

Comment: It's a template, and the compiler has to generate code for it, even if there is a condition which would stop the template initialization.

Comment: ah ok I see. but how can i do this in a correct way?

Comment: One way is to use `enable_if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Bar<T>` is not a subclass of `T`,

```
Bar<T> & bar = *ptr;
```

this results in a compilation error. The fact that this is wrapped inside an `if()` statement that evaluates to `false`, and this section of the code will never be executed, doesn't change this fact.

The correct approach here is to specialize the template.

Something along these lines:

```
template <class T, bool is_subclass=std::is_base_of<Bar<T>,T>::value>
void foo(T * ptr);

template <class T>
void foo<T, true>(T * ptr){
    ...a lot of code ...

    Bar<T> & bar = *ptr;
    ...a lot of code ...

    ...a lot of code    
}

template <class T>
void foo<T, false>(T * ptr){
    ...a lot of code ...

    ...a lot of code    
}
```

You now have two different versions of the `foo` template, one for the case when the template parameter is a subclass, and one that does not.

It is likely that both versions of `foo()` will have a large amount of common code. So, you will likely need to do more work here, factoring out the common code into standalone template functions of their own, that you will invoke from both `foo()`s.

Answer (score 1):

this can be achieved in multiple ways, one example is tag dispatch:

```
template <class T>
void bar(T* ptr, std::true_type)
{
    // ...a lot of code ...
}

template <class T>
void bar(T*, std::false_type)
{
    // do nothing
}

template <class T>
void foo(T * ptr){
    //...a lot of code ...
    bar(ptr, std::is_base_of<Bar<T>,T>{});
    //...a lot of code    
}
```